# Is there any way to open the default Share item dialog from the SPFx webpart

Tags: spfx, list-item, spfx-extensions, share, dialog

Is there any way to Open the Default Share Item dialog from the SPFx web part's details list (Modern dialog)?

[image]

My requirement is to open the default OOTB share item dialog (as displayed above) when someone clicks on the context item inside the Details list item.

Answer (score 0):

The following link will give you the "Share with" dialog. You can put it in a Modal dialog of your preference:

```
[webURL]/_layouts/15/sharedialog.aspx?listId={[listID]}&listItemId=[listItemID]&clientId=listPart&ma=0
```

Have fun!
ps.
I guess if you are working on SPFx you might choose this:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/tree/master/src/controls/iFrameDialog